# How to write regex for redirection

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have some url's

```
/a/b?key1=value&key2=value
/a/b/?key1=value&key2=value
```

I want to redirect them to the url

```
/a/b/c/?key1=value&key2=value
```

What i have done till now is 
i am able to redirect the `/a/b/`  to `/a/b/c` using regex

```
^(\/.*\/)$
```

also i can not hard code `b` in the url since it is dynamic and may vary.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about the regex,

```
^((?:/[^/?]+){2})/?
```

- Replace with `$1/c`
- `/[^/?]+` Matches `/`, followed by anything other than `/` or `?`.

  The `{2}` Makes sure that it is repeated twice, once for `a` and the other for `b`. This entire match is captured in group 1.
- `/?` Matches an optional `/` at the end.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/J8lxAP/1)

Comment: how to i get the query string ?

Comment: @EkanshRastogi Here we won't be touching the query params at all. We are matching till the query params. If you are still interested you can use `\?[^?]+$` to match the query params

Comment: thanks for help, this will work for 2nd url i mentioned but nor for first url

Comment: @EkanshRastogi Can you try replacing the last `?` with `*` and check? I think the zero or one pattern using `?` is not supported